# Calling WordPress hook from within a class: call to undefined function error

Tags: php, oop

I am new to OOP with WordPress and could use some help with debugging this issue. I have been searching for an answer and been trying to debug myself, but could use a hand. I am trying to create admin menu items and their pages, but I am getting the following error:

`Whoops\Exception\ErrorException thrown with message "call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'create_admin_page' not found or invalid function name"`

can anyone help point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Here is my class.

```
namespace MyNamespace;


class MyClass {


    public function __construct() {
        add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'create_menu_item'));
        //add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'remove_wp_logo', 999);
        //add_filter( 'admin_bar_menu', 'change_howdy', 25 );

        ddd($this->create_menu_item());


    }

//Get all pages

    public function get_all_pages() {
        $allpages = get_pages( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'posts_per_page' => '-1') );
        return $allpages;

    }

    //Get Parent Page ID
    protected function get_location_id() {
        $parents = get_page_by_title('Locations');        
        return  $parents->ID;
    }

    //Get all locations excluding grandchildren
    protected function get_top_level_pages() {
        $children = get_page_children( $this->get_location_id(), $this->get_all_pages() );
        $locations = array();
        foreach ($children as $key => $value) {
            if ($this->get_location_id() == $value->post_parent) {
                $locations[$key] = $this->{$key} = $value;
            }
        }
        return $locations;
    }
    //Create top level menu item
    public function create_menu_item() {

        $locations = $this->get_top_level_pages();
        foreach ($locations as $key => $value) {
            add_menu_page( 
                $value->post_title, 
                $value->post_title, 
                'manage_options', 
                $value->post_name.'-admin-page.php', 
                'create_admin_page', //here is where I am calling the next function
                'dashicons-location-alt', 
                6  
            );

        }

    }

//Create Admin Page -----should be it's own class? 
    public function create_admin_page() {
        $children = get_page_children( $this->get_location_id(), $this->get_all_pages() );
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h2>Welcome Child Pages</h2>
        </div>
            <ul>
            <?php 
                if(!empty($children)){
                    echo '<ul>';
                    foreach($children as $child){
                        echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($child->ID).'">'.$child->post_title.'</a></li>';
                    }
                    echo '</ul>';
                }    
            ?>
            </ul>
        <?php

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line:

```
add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'create_menu_item'));
```

You are correctly passing the `create_menu_item` method of the current class to callback argument of the `add_action()` function. You just need to apply the same principle for the callbacks in the `add_menu_page()` function:

```
add_menu_page( 
    $value->post_title, 
    $value->post_title, 
    'manage_options', 
    $value->post_name.'-admin-page.php', 
    array( $this, 'create_admin_page' ), // <-- Here
    'dashicons-location-alt', 
    6  
);
```

This will apply to any WordPress function that has a 'callback' as a parameter. You can read more about callbacks in PHP [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

Comment: That worked perfectly! I have been reading about callables and callbacks, but it looks like I still have some studying to do. Thank you!